# How to update a table based on multiple conditions in another

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in a Microsoft SQL server database, simplistically

```sql
create table items
(
    id        int identity,
    source    varchar(10),
    value     int,
    ingest_id int not null,
    row       int
)

create table messages
(
    id        int identity,
    ingest_id int          not null,
    row       int          not null,
    code      varchar(10) not null
)
```

There may be zero or more messages for each unique combination of `ingest_id` and `row`. I would like to update the `items` table such that for each message where the code is `FOO` the corresponding row in the `items` table is updated to `BAR`

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work?